# Threejs Transform Matrix ordering

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js

I would like to know how threejs ordering multiple matrix?

For instance ,

```
......
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.position.set( 0, 20, 0 ); // T , transform matrix
mesh.rotation.set( 0, Math.PI, 0 );//R , rotation matrix
mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 10 );//S , scale matrix
```

So , how threejs to combine three matrix? It will according my set value order(In my example , it is TRS , so final matrix should T*R*S ) or fixed order (For instance, it is always using SRT ordering , the finally matrix is S*R*T)?

Comment: The order you specify is irrelevant. Since in three.js, matrix  multiplication is on the left, the final matrix is T * R * S.

Comment: Thanks for your answer first! so if i change code in to 
mesh.scale.set( 1, 1, 10 );//S , scale matrix
mesh.position.set( 0, 20, 0 ); // T , transform matrix
mesh.rotation.set( 0, Math.PI, 0 );//R , rotation matrix
finally matrix will be S*T*R , right?

Comment: No. See my first sentence. Scale is always applied first, then rotation, then translation.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It is very cleanly!

Comment: Is it `T*R*S*X` or `X*T*R*S` ? (If T R S are matrices and X is a vector3)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the parameters as you have done so long as the mesh property 'matrixAutoUpdate' is true and you only want it in order by scale, rotation then translation (typical).

If you need something more complicated, such as a specific series of translations and rotations, then you should set matrixAutoUpdate to false and calculate the matrix yourself.

Important note: when using the matrix multiply function, you must do it in 'reverse' order. For example if you want to position a limb then logically you would:

1) do local rotation (such as arm up/down)

2) move limb with respect to its offset (put it at its joint)

3) rotate according to body rotation

4) move to body offset

The actual operations would be done in reverse:

```js
arm_mesh.matrixAutoUpdate = false;

var mat4: THREE.Matrix4 = new THREE.Matrix4();
var arm_matrix = arm_mesh.matrix;

arm_matrix.identity();  // reset

arm_matrix.multiply(mat4.makeTranslation(body_pos.x, body_pos.y, body_pos.z));
arm_matrix.multiply(mat4.makeRotationFromQuaternion(body_rotation));
arm_matrix.multiply(mat4.makeTranslation(arm_offset.x, arm_offset.y, arm_offset.z));
arm_matrix.multiply(mat4.makeRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(arm_angle, 0, 0)));
```

Of course this does not utilize or account for parent/child relationships.